# Check bluetooth connection from terminal in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, terminal, bluetooth

I want to connect a bluetooth device to my PC.

How can I check if the connection is active only using the DOS terminal in Windows 7? Which commands could I use?

Answer (score -1):

On Windows, a simple command line `ipconfig` displays the bluetooth adapter if the module is activated

```
Ethernet adapter Bluetooth Network Connection 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12382797/2308068)

Comment: Thanks, but the bluetooth device is mapped to a serial port. ipconfig always gives the same result, even if I know the bluetooth device is connected.

Comment: I'm not sure [this](http://www.computerhope.com/modehlp.htm) will help you (I don't have anything similar to BT device attached to serial port, so I can't check this)